# Android Facebook Share Photo with Text as Link

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

Facebook SDK keeps on changing, and I would like to know how to upload a photo (when sharing) with separate text (not embedded).

```
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                    .setBitmap(newBitmap)
                    .setUserGenerated(true)
                    .build();

            SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                    .addPhoto(photo)
                    .build();


            ShareDialog.show(Main.this, content);
```

Is there a way to put the text after the photo, or even have the share message (where the user can type) pre-filled with some text?
By the way, I'm using the this version of FB:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I understand the down votes now. Not reading the policies (only because I never really do). It states there that:

> Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message parameter of posts with content a person didn’t create, even if the person can edit or remove the content before sharing.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Answer (score 0):

pre-fill text-with-image is no longer work

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill